# Importing data from an API and exporting it into MySQL database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I am trying to import JSON data from an API and export it into my MySQL database by using a Python script. I am getting this error in my code:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

So I was looking at similar articles on StackOverflow regarding this error, but I've only seen ones where the programmer is trying to manually input values. I see that posts about this usually regard missing a comma or not specifying all the columns, and then they fix that. In my case I'm trying to import data from an API and I'm assuming not manually stating the values is what's causing the problem? Don't know how to work around that though.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import pymysql

r = requests.get('https://data.cdc.gov/resource/vbim-akqf')
package_json=r.json()

con = pymysql.connect(host = 'x.x.x.x', user = 'x', passwd = 'x', db = 'x')
cursor = con.cursor()

def validate_string(val):
    if val != None:
        if type(val) is int:
            return str(val).encode('utf-8')
        else:
            return val

for i in package_json:
    t1=[] 
    for x in i:
        xx=validate_string(i.get(x, None))
        t1.append(xx)
    cursor.execute("""Insert into covid_data (cdc_case_earliest_dt, cdc_report_dt, pos_spec_dt, onset_dt, current_status, sex, age_group, race_ethnicity_combined, hosp_yn, icu_yn, death_yn, medcond_yn) VALUES {} """ .format(tuple(t1)))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

My main problem is that as you can see, I have specific columns I am trying to populate. I'm not specifying values because I want all values taken from the API. I don't know if I'm doing this right but my code is following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@himanshu_88759/how-to-import-data-from-csv-file-and-from-apis-into-mysql-database-using-python-763fb8957acc

How can I populate the MySQL table with the values? Am I supposed to reformat that "INSERT INTO" line somehow so that it takes the values from the API endpoint? This picture just shows what the data from the API looks like in a CSV format. You can see where I get the column names from. [image]

**EDIT**: Here is a pic of the column names in my MySQL database, all aligned the same as the ones in my Insert statement.[image]

Comment: Look at your t1 array before your insert. The error is quite literal. it need to match the number of columns you listed in `Insert into covid_data`

Comment: @danblack Looking now at the t1=[] line. How do I make it match / what's it supposed to look like? New at Python so I'm not exactly sure...

Comment: count the number of entries in `t1`. How many column names do you list in your `insert` statement? If they don't equal, work out why.

Comment: @danblack So, I have 12 column names listed in my insert statement. The table of data produced from the API would also have 12. I made sure to check to see if they're all listed correctly in the insert statement. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, am I just not clarifying in my code for t1=[] correctly or something like that?

Comment: looks right. Print the `t1` when its length != 12 and see what you get.

Comment: @danblack After t1=[], I did a `if ((len(t1) != 12: print("not equal to 12")` ... I executed it and the statement did indeed print. I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.. I have also posted a screenshot of my table in MySQL to show that I have the same column names as the one in my "Insert Into" statement. Please let me know if you can see what may be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you have to do is build up your query along with your value list. For example:

```
# some test data I made up
package_json = [
    {
        'cdc_case_earliest_dt'  : 'a', 
        'cdc_report_dt'         : 'b', 
        'pos_spec_dt'           : 'c', 
        'onset_dt'              : 'd', 
        'current_status'        : 'e', 
        'sex'                   : 'f', 
        'age_group'             : 'g', 
        'race_ethnicity_combined' : 'h',
        'hosp_yn'               : 'i', 
        'icu_yn'                : 'j', 
        'death_yn'              : 'k', 
        'medcond_yn'            : 'l'
    }
]

for i in package_json:
    # start off your query string
    query = 'Insert into covid_data ('
    t1=[]
    first_item = True
    for x in i:
        xx=validate_string(i.get(x, None))
        # append the value to the value list
        t1.append(xx)
        if not first_item:
            # add a comma and space to the query if it's not the first item
            query += ', '
        # add the field name to the query
        query += x
        # mark that it's no longer the first item
        first_item = False

    # finish off the query string
    query += ') VALUES {}'
    # and send the query
    cursor.execute(query.format(tuple(t1)))
```

the above the data will produce:

```
Insert into covid_data (cdc_case_earliest_dt, cdc_report_dt, pos_spec_dt, onset_dt, current_status, sex, age_group, race_ethnicity_combined, hosp_yn, icu_yn, death_yn, medcond_yn) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l')
```

This way, you'll always have matching number of fields and data values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will try this out. But I'm wondering how can it work if I want to insert all rows of data from this API (extracted as JSON)? I see that you put in some test data for package_json. But I have tons of data that needs to be added from the API. Is there some way to work around this? Or does the way you put it already work for it and it was just dummy code to allow it to have matching number of fields and data values? Thanks.

Comment: And isn't `r.json()` already assigned to `package_json`? Which is taken from `r = requests.get('https://data.cdc.gov/resource/vbim-akqf')` That link right there is the API endpoint. Let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your `package_json` is from `r.json()`, just leave that as it is. I don't know what is in your `r`, so I just plugged in a set of test data based on your list of fields to show how the for loop would work. You have to try it out to see if it works for you. If you do a `print(r)` and paste the printout as an example data into your question, it will give us a better idea what you're dealing with. I'm showing you the general principal of how you need to match each field in your `INSERT` query with a value.